# How to connect Visual studio Code to Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I have connecting command prompt to salesforce using below commands.

```
D:
cd salesforce CLI
cd bin
sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub
```

But i cant able to connect Visual studio code to salesforce. i have installed visual studio code in my system. at the same time `Salesforce CLI Integration` and `Salesforce Extension Pack` also installed. but selecforce connecting commands are not showing.

how to connect visual studio code to salesforce. And what are the commands we need to pass.

Comment: There are no commands to pass; once everything is installed, it should just work. Have you (a) restarted VS Code and/or (b) restarted your computer? Also, if Salesforce CLI is not in your %PATH%, VS Code will not be able to work with it. I recommend restarting and/or reinstalling Salesforce DX to see if that fixes things.

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect VSCode to Salesforce orgs, you need to install:

- SFDX CLI (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm)

  Also please make sure you can run 'sfdx' command from any folder in the command prompt (cmd) and not only from the folder where `sfdx cli` is installed
- Salesforce Extension Pack (Open VSCode -> Extensions -> Search for Salesforce Extension Pack)

When you have SFDX Cli and Salesforce Extension Pack installed you need to create a project folder for your org. You can either run the following command in terminal/command prompt

```
sfdx force:project:create --projectname "name of your's project folder" --manifest
```

or in VSCode open "Command Pallete" and type `SFDX: Create Project` and follow the wizard.

[image]

After you have a project folder in SFDX format you will be able to connect it to the Salesforce org. To do so you have a few options:

- Authorize a new org through the cli and set it as default for the current project (you need to run that command from the project folder)

```
sfdx force:auth:web -a "alias-for-the-org" --setdefaultusername
```

- Set previously authorized org as the default org for the current project

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=alias-for-another-org
```

- Open "Org Launcher" in the VSCode and select previously authorized org / authorize a new one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of not connecting to salesforce but I followed below link and was able to reinstall everything.

change the org to your org in project-scratch-def.json and use SFDX: Authorize an org
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce/start-vscode

Comment: Also follow https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/getting-started/install and this has perfect examples

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Download and Install VsCode 
Step 2) Install Salesforce DX CLI  
Step 3) Install Salesforce Extension Pack 
Open your VsCode and Click on Extensions icon on left hand side or press
CTRL+SHIFT+X. Then Search for “Salesforce Extension Pack” and click on
install button.Till this step your software setup is completed. 
Step 4) Create Project
To Create the project open Command Palette or press Ctrl + Shift + P.
Then type "SFDX: Create Project with Manifest". Then provide your
project name and select location where you want to save your project.
Step 5) Connect with your Salesforce Org
Open Command Palette or press Ctrl + Shift + P. This time we need to
type or Select “SFDX: Authorize an Org“.
Step 6) Retrieve Component
Open Package.xml file from Manifest folder. Then Modify your
Package.xml file to add and remove component. Finally Click on
Package.xml and select “SFDX: Retrieve This Source from Org” option
Step 7) Deploy component
Do your changes in VSCode and then select the file which you want to
deploy in your org. Then Right click on VsCode and select “SFDC:
Deploy This Source to Org” option for deployment.